# Optimal Regular Expression: match sets of lines starting with 

Tags: ruby, regex

Alright, this one's interesting. I have *a* solution, but I don't like it.

The goal is to be able to find a set of lines that start with 3 periods - not an individual line, mind you, but a collection of all the lines in a row that match. For example, here's some matches (each match is separated by a blank line):

```
...

...hello

...
...hello
...world
...
...wazzup?
...
```

My solution is as follows:

```
^\.\.\..*(\n\.\.\..*)*$
```

It matches all those, so it's what I'm using for now - however, it looks kinda silly to repeat the `\.\.\..*` pattern. Is there a simpler way?

Please [test your regex](http://regexpal.com/) before submitting it, rather than submit what "should work." For example, I tried the following first:

```
(^\.\.\..*$)+
```

which only returned individual lines, even though in my mind it looks like it would do the trick - I guess I just don't understand regex internals. (And no, I didn't need to set any flags to get ^ and $ to match line boundaries, since I'm implementing this in Ruby.)

So I'm not totally sure there's a good answer, but one would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to specify the language you're using because everyone made a different implementation. .NET? perl? javascript?

Comment: Just to say that I'd probably just use regular code; most languages make it easy to read a file (etc) line-by-line and check that a string starts with a few characters...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I specified Ruby in there... right?

Comment: Also, due to my particular circumstance, this seems like the best approach. The lines are a part of a text template of sorts (stored in a database - Rails, should have mentioned), so I'm trying to drop in replacement text based on field submitted via HTTP POST. For other areas involving that templating system, like displaying the actual content, I use normal code, but replacement seemed much easier with this route :)

Comment: Matchu: Usually you want to add a tag with the language as well so people can easily see "it's a regex question on ruby" by the tags alone.

Comment: I considered it, but it wasn't quite clear to me that the regex engine was quite that vital. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most regex implementations you can shorten `\.\.\.` using `\.{3}` so your solution would turn into `\.{3}.*(\n\.{3}.*)*`.

Comment: Seems to even grab empty lines, though =/ : http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=^%28\n*\.{3}.*%29*%24&input=...if%20all%20these%20are%20yellow%0A%0A...%0A...they%27re%20part%20of%20the%20same%20match%0A...%0A%0A%0A%0A...which%20isn%27t%20desired%20behavior%20-%20darn!

Comment: But I do appreciate the shortening - that's step one :D

Comment: I hadn't fully grasped your requirements till now, sorry. I can't think of a shorter solution so I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The solution incorrectly matches lines like this: "foo...bar".

Comment: Monty's right, there should be a ^ at the very beginning of that regex.

Answer (score 1):

What you already have is already simple and understandable. Keep in mind that more "clever" RegExps may very well be slower and undoubtedly less readable.

Assuming lines are terminated by a `\n`:

```
((^|\n)\.{3}[^\n]*)+
```

I am not familiar with Ruby, so depending on how it returns matches you might need to "nonmatch" groups:

```
((?:(?:^|\n)\.{3}[^\n]*)+)
```

Comment: Excellent point: some benchmarking showed that this more compressed regex performed at about two-thirds the speed.

I'm not sure, then, what I do now in regards to this question... I guess I'll just mark the other since it's the only shortening I can really feel comfortable doing - though I'm disappointed there's no "simple" answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([.]{3}.*$\n?)+
```

This doesn't really need `$` in there.

Comment: What is the $ doing in the middle of the pattern?

Comment: '$' matches the end of a line or the end of the whole string. If it's the end of a line, '\n?' consumes the linefeed so matching can continue on the next line.  So the '$' in the middle of the regex is pulling its weight, but the one at the end is redundant.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think the greediness of regular expressions will ensure that entire lines are consumed, so both $ characters can be removed from the pattern: /^([.]{3}.*\n?)+/

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to a solution with `(^\.\.\..*$)+`, but because the `+` modifier is on the outside of the group, it is getting overwritten each time and you are only left with the last line. Try wrapping it in an outer group: `((^\.\.\..*$)+)` and looking at the first submatch and ignoring the inner one.

Combined with the other suggestion: `((^\.{3}.*$)+)`

Comment: I say ignore the inner one because you disliked the increased complexity in Borgar's response. You could non-match the inner group to ignore it complete: ((?:^\.{3}.*$)+)

Comment: Fortunately, I'm not concerned with grouping in this case. I don't need submatches. I just need matches that I'm going to replace in order :) So grouping wasn't the issue with that solution. It just wasn't making the right matches at all.